# SSO Connect App: "Data Not Available"

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml

We are working in a sandbox and have recreated a connected app we use for SSO.  When we try to load the `IdP-Initiated Login URL` I get a **Data Not Available** error.

[image: Connect App Data not available]

I get the same error when I try to `Download Metadata` button as well...

I also can't edit any of the fields from the Connect App page (it will let me go to the edit screen but when I try to save my changes, the page refreshes back to the view and the previous values are still in place).

Any idea what could be going on?  Almost seems like some internal Salesforce wackyness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Setup and look under your Identity Provider, I assume it's enabled?    If so, we probably need to look at your org quick.

If that's the case, I need your OrgId.   Email me at cmortimore at salesforce or post it here.

Comment: didn't have the IDP enbabled.  Thanks

Comment: BTW do you where this requirement is mentioned in the documentation?  The reference I've been using doesn't mention it at all: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=quickstart_oauth.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fquickstart_oauth.htm|SkinName=webhelp